# What does "las comprendidas" mean?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, adjetivos, participio

### Question

1. "Las Comprendidas"
   In my understanding, **Comprendida** comes from "comprender" (understand). However, not sure how to understand it in the example below. Does it have a specific meaning which is not exactly related with "understanding"?
2. "y se llaman líneas divisorias"
   Does this sentence refer to the "dos líneas verticales"? It looks the subject has been "las figuras y silencios" and it seems odd that the subject has been changed to "lineas verticales". Is this normal in Spanish?

### Sentences

> El Compás sirve para concretar la duración de las notas y se indica con su signo respectivo al principio del trazo musical a que se refiere; las figuras y silencios correspondientes a un Compás son ***las comprendidas*** entre dos líneas verticales que atraviesan la pauta, y se llaman líneas divisorias.

### Translation (trying)

> The Tempo serves to realize the duration of the notes and it is indicated with it respective sign at the beginning of music chart it refers to. The music notes and silence marks to agree with a Tempo are the "comprendidas" between two vertical lines which cross through the rules, and called dividing lines.

[image]

Comment: Comprendidas--comprised. "Se les llama" debe verse como parte de la oración subordinada, y el sujeto es el mismo "que" de "que atraviesan la pauta"; quizá se entienda mejor sin la coma.

Comment: @walen I've done minor fixes to this question to make it on-topic. Now it asks for the meaning rather than the translation.

Comment: @Charlie very good idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb *[comprender](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A34eRFg)* has other meanings in Spanish apart from *understand*. See the following definitions:

> 1. tr. Abrazar, ceñir o rodear por todas partes algo.
>
> 2. tr. Contener o incluir en sí algo. U. t. c. prnl.

So in this case, the verb *comprender* is a synonym of *contener* (*contain*). And your translation must be something like "contained between two vertical lines".